# Type of Constructors for vector STL with list

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector

when you initialize an vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3};
```

Which constructor is called to perform this initialization?

Comment: number 10: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: aka `std::initializer_list<>`